# Uniform bound in $L^\infty(0,T;X)$ implies pointwise a.e. convergence in $Y$ if $X \subset Y$ is compact?

Tags: functional-analysis, solution-verification, weak-convergence, bochner-spaces

Suppose that $u_n \in L^\infty(0,T;X)$ is a uniformly bounded sequence, so $u_n \to u$ weakly-star to some $u$.

and that $X \subset Y$ is a compact embedding of Hilbert spaces. Does it follow that for a subsequence
$$u_n(t) \to u(t)$$
strongly in $Y$?

The argument is, since $u_n$ is bounded, we have for a.e. $t$ that
$$\lVert u_n(t) \rVert_X \leq C$$
bounded uniformly. So there is a subsequence $u_{n_j}(t) \to w(t)$ in $Y$ by the compact embedding for a.e. $t$. And then we can identify $u(t) = w(t)$, is that right?

Comment: When you write $L^\infty(0,T;X)$ do you mean measurable function from $[0,T]$ to $X$ with finite essential supremum?

Comment: Yes that's right, the Bochner space

Answer (score 2):

This is not true even for $X=Y=\mathbb R$. Define
$$
u_n(t) = sign(\sin(n t))
$$
on $(0,T):=(0,2\pi)$. This sequence converges weakly to $0$ in all $L^p$, $1\le p<\infty$, and weak-star to $0$ in $L^\infty$. Since $|u_n(t)|=1$ for almost all $t$ and all $n$, there is no subsequence that converges pointwise a.e. to zero.

---

There are several problems in your argument. First, the map $t\mapsto u(t)$ is not continuous in $L^p$-spaces. Second, ignoring this, then you cannot go from

> For all $t$ there is a subsequence $(u_{n_k})$ such that $u_{n_k}(t)$ converges.

to

> There is a subsequence $(u_{n_k})$  such that $u_{n_k}(t)$ converges for all $t$.

Comment: I agree with the problem you pointed out, but it is true that there is a t-dependent subsequence $n_j(t)$ such that $u_{n_j(t)}(t) \to w(t)$ in $Y$ strongly for almost every $t$. I don't see how I am using the continuity of $t \mapsto u(t)$ in what I wrote though..